# jq: build lookup table

Tags: json, hashtable, jq

I'm trying to build a lookup table in jq.

Input:

```
  {
    "Object1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "object1name"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "object2name"
    }
  }
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "object1name":1,
    "object2name":2 
}
```

I tried the following jq code but it gives me an error:

```
{.[] | ((.name):.id)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect the objects in an array and reduce it with `add`:

```
$ jq '[.[] | {(.name): .id}] | add' tmp.json
{
  "object1name": 1,
  "object2name": 24
}
```

You can write the filter a little more tersely as `map({(.name): .id}) | add`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Why doesn't my code though? Why is it possible to expand an object/array inside an array but not inside an object?

Comment: The `:` isn't really an operator; it's just part of the syntax for an object literal, so it has to be inside braces, not parentheses. That means you need `{(.name): .id}` as part of an answer. Similarly, you *have* to have key-value pairs, not lone values, inside `{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't my code [work] though?

You were close!  Although @chepner's answers are the most straightforward, an answer along the lines you seem to have been thinking is certainly possible:

```
[ {(.[] | .name): .id}] | add
```